# How do I run multiple bots with threading in discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to make a python script that would run multiple discord bots at a time. I have to do this because there is a limit to how many messages you can send within a certain period of time. Why doesn't my code work? Is there anyway to disable the limit to how many messages you can send?

```
import discord
import threading
from discord.ext import commands

class bot(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, token):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.token = token


    def run(self):
        client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='*')
        
        @client.event
        async def on_ready():
            x = []
            for i in client.get_all_channels():
                if i.name.isnumeric():
                    x.append(i)

            await i.send('Message')

        client.run(self.token)


bot1 = bot('ExampelToken1')
bot2 = bot('ExampelToken2')
bot3 = bot('ExampelToken3')
bot4 = bot('ExampelToken4')
bot5 = bot('ExampelToken5')
th1 = threading.Thread(target=bot1.run,args=())
th2 = threading.Thread(target=bot2.run,args=())
th3 = threading.Thread(target=bot3.run,args=())
th4 = threading.Thread(target=bot4.run,args=())
th5 = threading.Thread(target=bot5.run,args=())
th1.start()
th2.start()
th3.start()
th4.start()
th5.start()
```

I am getting the error:

```
File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 644, in get_event_loop
    % threading.current_thread().name)
RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-10'.
```

Comment: You are creating two threads per bot one from using `bot()` and one from using `Thread()`.

Comment: You actually do not need to create a new thread for each bot. Since the bot support asyncio you can have multiple bots running in parallel in the same thread. See this issue for details: https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues/516